# undefined constant SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES

Tags: magento2, installation, magento2.4.1

I am trying to access frontend of magento 2.4.3
But getting

> Use of undefined constant
> SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES - assumed
> 'SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES' (this will throw
> an Error in a future version of PHP) in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php
> on line 40

error.

I have enabled sodium php extension too.

Any thoughts on fixing this issue?

Comment: can you check the sodium php extension is installed

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't have access to SSH
I have shared hosting Cpanel
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

For me works

1. Add "extension=sodium" to php.ini (no quotes)
2. Copy php/libsodium.dll to apache/bin/
3. Restart Server